# How to auto-notify ListView that its bound property has changed, the MVVM's way?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

How to auto-notify ListView that its bound property has changed, the MVVM's way ?

Relevant code-behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public DataModel StoreHouse { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<Units> Devices { get { return StoreHouse.Units; } }
    /*
    ... rest of the code ...
    */
}
```

XAML binding:

```
<ListView Name="UnitsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Devices}">
```

When I do this:

```
StoreHouse = newDeserializedStoreHouse
```

The `Units` property is no longer valid. Now I can use `DependencyProperty`, and do this:

```
StoreHouse = newDeserializedStoreHouse
Units = StoreHouse.Units;
```

But it's not MVVM-ish... is there a way to do it automatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Storehouse and the Units are dependent, they should probably be in the same Viewmodel.

You could then just put the ViewModel in the DataContext of the View and bind to both the Storehouse and the Units by speficying the correct binding paths.

Replacing the storehouse is then a change to the ViewModel that could also update the Units or you could set up a completely new ViewModel and assign it to the DataContext.

Answer (score 1):

Use `INotifyPropertyChanged` for your properties, e.g. like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<Thing> _things;

public ObservableCollection<Thing> Things
{
    get { return _things; }
    private set 
    {
        if ( _things != value )
        {
            _things = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}

public PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
private void OnPropertyChanged( [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "" )
{
    var evt = PropertyChanged;
    if ( evt != null)
    {
        evt( this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs( propertyName ) );
    }
}
```

Do note the use of `CallerMemberName` on the `propertyName` parameter; the C# compiler will replace that parameter value with the name of the member in which you call the method, e.g. `Things` in our example. This is useful to avoid hard-coded strings, which introduce the risk of forgetting to change them if you change the property name. This is available in C# 5 on .NET 4.5; if you use an older C# version, you'll have to use hard-coded strings. (or do magic with expressions, but that's a lot more complex to do)

Many MVVM frameworks have a base class to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` easily.

Comment: Do you suggest that I implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my `MainWindow` (since there are all the properties, and `DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"` )?

Comment: Yes, if the properties are in your MainWindow, you should do that. But theoretically, in "pure" MVVM, your window's DataContext should be a ViewModel and have no dependencies on the window or any assembly related to WPF. (also, it makes it easier to inherit from a base `INotifyPropertyChanged` class)